# Problem with creating a 3D mask of DICOM-RT contour data using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, medical-imaging

I have troubles extracting a tumor using a RT mask from a dicom image. Due to GDPR I am not allowed to share the dicom images even though they are anonymized. However I am allowed to share the images themself. I want to extract the drawn tumor from the CT images using the draw GTV stored as a RT structure using MATLAB.

Lets say that the file directory where my CT images are stored is called DicomCT and that the RT struct dicom file is called rtStruct.dcm.

I can read and visualize my CT images as follows:

```
V = dicomreadVolume(“DicomCT”);
V = squeeze(V);
volshow(V)
```

[volume V - 3D CT image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sjMn.png)

I can load my rt structure using:

```
Info = dicominfo(“rtStruct.dcm”);
rtContours = dicomContours(Info);
I get the plot giving the different contours.
plotContour(rtContours)
```

[Contours for the GTV of the CT image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8WfH.png)

I used this link for the information on how to create the mask such that I can apply it to the 3D CT image: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/create-and-display-3-d-mask-of-dicom-rt-contour-data.html#d124e5762
The dicom information tells mee the image should be 3mm slices, hence I took 3x3x3 for the referenceInfo.

```
referenceInfo = imref3d(size(V),3,3,3);
rtMask = createMask(rtContours, 1, referenceInfo)
```

When I plot my rtMask, I get a grey screen without any trace of the mask. I think that something is wrong with the way that I define the referenceInfo, but I have no idea how to fix it or what is wrong.

```
volshow(rtMask)
```

[Volume plot of the RT mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW4ob.png)

What would be the best way forward?

Answer (score 1):

i was actually having some sort of similar problem to you a couple of days ago. I think you might have two possible problems (none of them your fault).
Your grey screen might be an error rendering that it's not showing because of how the actual volshow() script works. I found it does some things i don't understand with graphics memory and representing numeric type volumes vs logic volumes. I found this the hard way in my job PC where i only have intel HD graphics. Using

```
iptsetpref('VolumeViewerUseHardware',true)
```

for logical volumes worked fine for me. You an also test this by trying to replot the mask as double instead of logical by

```
rtMask = double(rtMask)
volshow(rtMask)
```

If it's not a rendering error caused by the interactions between your system and volshow() it might be an actual confusion and how the createMask and the actual reference info it needs (created by an actual bad explanation in the tutorial you just linked). Using pixel size info instead of actual axes limits can create partial visualization in segmentation or even missing it bc of scale. This nice person explained more elegantly in this post by using actual geometrical info of the dicom contours as limits.
https://es.mathworks.com/support/search.html/answers/1630195-how-to-convert-dicom-rt-structure-to-binary-mask.html?fq%5B%5D=asset_type_name:answer&fq%5B%5D=category:images/basic-import-and-export&page=1

basically use

```
plotContour(rtContours);                                            
ax = gca;                                                           
referenceInfo = imref3d(size(V),ax.XLim,ax.YLim,ax.ZLim);
rtMask = createMask(rtContours, 1, referenceInfo)
```

In addition to your code and it might work.

I hope this could be of help to you.